# How to implementation hashcode method for my class with a string method

Tags: java, overriding, equals, hashcode

I have an abstract class and I wanted to force all the implementations of the class to implement there own equals and hashCode method. The class has just one method which returns a String.

The abstract class is defined like this

```
public abstract class Type
{
   public abstract String getType();
   public abstract boolean equals(Object other);
   public abstract int hashCode();
}
```

I have implemented the equals method. Now I am implementing the hashCode method for this class. I have a couple of questions:

1) Is this the right approach to override the == behavior in all implementations of the class.

2) What would be the best way to implement the hashCode method for this class which only has one function that returns a string?

Is this is a duplicate, please point me to the right answer.

Comment: Nit: you can't override the `==` behaviour, only the `equals` behaviour.

Comment: "What would be the best way" Entirely depends on what you're trying to do. *A* way would be simply to use `return getType().hashCode();`.

Comment: And `hashCode` is not needed for `equals` behavior. It's needed for `HashMap` and `HashSet` though, so it's always best to implement it if `equals` is implemented.

Comment: @Andy and implement `equals()` as `return getType().equals(that.getType());` so it agrees with `hashCode()`

Comment: @Bohemian sure, after the `instanceof` check (and optionally the `this` check).

Comment: I have already implemented the equals method. The only thing I was concerned about was that there is no non-static fields in the class so return getType().hashCode() seems like the only option for this other than playing with prime numbers. Not sure which approach will be better to take.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes that is my implementation of equals with one exception. I have done Objects.equals(getType, that.getType()) instead of getType().equals(that.getType()). Would that be fine or should I change to string comparison?